# Use of column names in Redshift COPY command which is a reserved keyword

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have a table in redshift where the column names are 'begin' and 'end'. They are Redshift keywords. I want to explicitly use them in the Redshift COPY command. Is there a workaround rather than renaming the column names in the table. That will be my last option.

I tried to enclose them within single/double quotes, but looks like the COPY command only accepts comma separated column names.

Comment: When you say that you want to use them in the `COPY` command, is it because you want to create columns named `begin` and `end`, or is it because there is a column in the file already with those names?  Did you try `COPY tablename (foo, "begin", "end", bar)`?

Answer (score 3):

Copy command works fails if you don't escape keywords as column name. e.g. `begin` or `end`.

```
copy test1(col1,begin,end,col2) from 's3://example/file/data1.csv' credentials 'aws_access_key_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX;aws_secret_access_key=XXXXXXXXXXX' delimiter ',';
```

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "end"

But, it works fine if as `begin` and `end` are enclosed by double quote(`"`) as below.

```
copy test1(col1,"begin","end",col2) from 's3://example/file/data1.csv' credentials 'aws_access_key_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX;aws_secret_access_key=XXXXXXXXXXX' delimiter ',';
```

I hope it helps.
If there is some different error please update your question.